# Is there a way to use native call screen for VoIP app on Android when no SIM card is installed?

Tags: android, react-native

I'm writing a VoIP app using React Native and I'm using [React Native CallKeep](https://github.com/react-native-webrtc/react-native-callkeep) to handle the connection between the app and native call screen.

However, I encountered a problem when there is no SIM card installed on Android device. Then no phone accounts are available in the system and it doesn't allow me to use the native call screen.

It's a limitation of given library, but is there any way to show a native Android call screen at all (even considering a native Java code)? Or it's a limitation of Android API itself?

Answer (score 0):

The Android Telecom framework manages audio and video calls on an Android device. This includes SIM-based calls (e.g. using the Telephony framework) as well as VOIP calls provided by implementors of the ConnectionService API.

This can help you to complete.

https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/telecom#integrateCalling

Comment: First, I want to make my own VoIP app. I understand how it generally works but there is a specific case: I want to show system call dialog with no SIM card installed. Do you know if that's possible?